# How does adding gulp-babel cause a callback error?

Tags: javascript, gulp, babeljs

I'm trying to slightly modify a gulp boilerplate by adding gulp-babel to it.

I've added the babel preset to the Javascript tasks in my gulpfile:

```
var jsTasks = lazypipe()
    .pipe(header, banner.full, {
        package: package
    })
    .pipe(optimizejs)
    .pipe(dest, paths.scripts.output)
    .pipe(rename, {
        suffix: '.min'
    })
    .pipe(babel, {
        presets: ['es2015']
    })
    .pipe(uglify)
    .pipe(optimizejs)
    .pipe(header, banner.min, {
        package: package
    })
    .pipe(dest, paths.scripts.output);
```

The error I'm getting:

```
[13:47:27] Finished 'default' after 429 ms
error!
events.js:174
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: write callback called multiple times
    at DestroyableTransform.afterTransform (/Users/mac/dev/gulp-boilerplate/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_transform.js:84:31)
    at Stream.<anonymous> (/Users/mac/dev/gulp-boilerplate/node_modules/gulp-flatmap/index.js:62:9)
    at Stream.emit (events.js:189:13)
    at Stream.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:459:23)
    at Pumpify.handleEnd (/Users/mac/dev/gulp-boilerplate/node_modules/duplexer/index.js:81:21)
    at Pumpify.emit (events.js:194:15)
    at Pumpify.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:459:23)
    at endReadableNT (/Users/mac/dev/gulp-boilerplate/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_readable.js:1010:12)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
Emitted 'error' event at:
    at DestroyableTransform.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:454:12)
    at DestroyableTransform.afterTransform (/Users/mac/dev/gulp-boilerplate/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_transform.js:84:17)
    at Stream.<anonymous> (/Users/mac/dev/gulp-boilerplate/node_modules/gulp-flatmap/index.js:62:9)
    [... lines matching original stack trace ...]
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
```

Without gulp-babel I'm not getting the error, but then I can not use ES6 in my code.
What exactly causes the callback error and how do I fix it?